# SimpleCV 1.3 is not

Tags: computer-vision, simplecv

I just install SimpleCV 1.3 on Windows 7. During the install I got a message: "this program could not have been correctly installed   setuptools-0.6c11.win32-py2.7.exe". When I run the first example

```
>>> logo = Image("simplecv")
>>> logo.show()
```

I got an empty python window and I get a warning: "You need the python image library to save by filehandle"
Someone knows how to fix this?

thanks in advance

Comment: loool, the tittle of my question is wrong and I dont know how to fix it :/

Answer (score 0):

After the install error message, did you try reinstalling?
SimpleCV is supposed to include all the libraries it needs, so when installation failed it must have missed some libraries.

You could try installing the python image library (PIL) yourself. 
I usually use this web site as a source of python libraries: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pil (I think you should use Pillow-2.0.0.win32-py2.7.‌exe)

Comment: I reinstalled SimpleCV like 4 times :(. On monday I will try installing PIL. I will post my results :P thanks